# How to get outer variable from .net core mvc view's function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I create a variable and function in view, how to get outer variable inside function ?

```
@{
    var myUrl = "https://example.com";
    @functions{
        private string ReplaceDomain(string replaceStr)
        {
            // Can't resolve symbol `myUrl`
            return myUrl.Replace("ABC", replaceStr);
        }
    }
}

<div>
My view
@ReplaceDomain("HAPPY")
@ReplaceDomain("BIRTHE")
@ReplaceDomain("DAY")
</div>
```

Always show "Can't resolve symbol `myUrl`" in function.

Is there any way to get outer variable **directly**?

Not like following method (not get variable directly)

```
@{
    var myUrl = "https://example.com";
    @functions{
        private string ReplaceDomain(string myUrl, string replaceStr)
        {
            // Can't resolve symbol `myUrl`
            return myUrl.Replace("ABC", replaceStr);
        }
    }
}

<div>
My view
@ReplaceDomain(myUrl, "HAPPY")
@ReplaceDomain(myUrl, "BIRTHE")
@ReplaceDomain(myUrl, "DAY")
</div>
```

Comment: why are you doing this at view level? I would do it at controller, ajax service or even better, javascript.

Comment: don't use a razor view function, just use a normal extension method for something like this

Comment: I create elements from a loop, every elements use function to get custom URL, but I don't want to use Javascript and AJAX. And I don't want create new view modal property, it huge and mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly define method in razor view, just change your code like below:

```
@{
    var myUrl = "https://example.com";
    string ReplaceDomain(string replaceStr)
    {
        return myUrl.Replace("ABC", replaceStr);
    }
    
}

<div>
    My view
    @ReplaceDomain("HAPPY")
    @ReplaceDomain("BIRTHE")
    @ReplaceDomain("DAY")
</div>
```